# How to use data table in ajax success?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter, data table and JQuery validation. I have to use a data table in ajax success function to display the records on view. There is no issue with records. All are displaying without data table. Now I have to use data table in ajax success. I don't know where should I use a data table.

Would you help me out how to use data table in ajax success?

**Jquery validation**

```
$("form[name='set_reports']").validate({
  rules: {
    report_type:{required:true}
  },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var report_type = $('#report_type').val();
        var fromDate = $('#fromDate').val();
        var toDate = $('#toDate').val();                              
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + "/Reports_control/Get_reports",
            method: "POST", 
            data: {report_type: report_type,fromDate:fromDate,toDate:toDate},
            success: function(response) {
            var data = JSON.parse(response);
          if (data.status === 'error')
             {
                alert(data.msg);
              } 

    if (data.status === 'success') {
      $('.report_list').show();
                var trHTML = '';
                    $.each(data.records, function (i, o){           
                    trHTML += '<tr><td>'+o.Sr_no+
                              '</td><td>' + o.cutomer_name +
                              '</td><td>'+ o.o_order_no +
                              '</td><td>'+ o.created_by +
                              '</td><td>'+ o.o_date_of_added +
                              '</td></tr>';
                          });
                  $('.search_record tbody').append(trHTML);
           }
         }
       });
}
    });
```

**Get_reports function**

```
 if (empty($getOutput) || $getOutput == 0){
    $arr_result['status'] = "error";
    $arr_result['msg'] = "No record found";
    }
 else 
    {
        $n=1;
      foreach ($getOutput as $row)
        {
        $results[] = array(
              "Sr_no" => $n,
              "cutomer_name" => $row->c_firstname.' '.$row->c_lastname,
              "o_order_no"=>$row->o_order_no,
              "created_by" =>$row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname,
              "o_date_of_added"=>$row->o_date_of_added
            );
        $n++;
          }
    $arr_result['status'] = 'success';
    $arr_result['records'] = $results;

        }
      echo json_encode($arr_result);
```

**View**

```
    <table cellspacing="0" id="datatable_list">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sr. No.</th>
          <th>Cutomer name</th>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Product Qty </th>
          <th>Order No</th>
          <th>Created By</th>
          <th>Date of Create</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>

<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#datatable_list').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

I tried this code but now issue is search is not working.Can anyone help me out on this issue?

Comment: You could initialize the datatable after you've populated the data.

Comment: @HazeErasmo I did in the view page but then search not working.

Comment: i meant to move the `$('#datatable_list').DataTable();` after the append code